# javascript replace document.documentElement.innerHTML

Tags: javascript

in a html page, i have

```
<html>
   <script>
       var cnt=''+document.documentElement.innerHTML+'';
cnt=cnt.replace(......);
   </script>
   <body> something else</body>
</html>
```

how to use replace function above, so that my 'cnt' var content is like below

```
<html>
  <body> something else</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.replace()` is not powerful enough for your case. Use this function:

```
function stripTags(var s) {
    var start = '<' + s + '>';
    var end = '</' + s + '>';

    while (true) {
        var pos1 = s.indexOf(start);
        var pos2 = s.indexOf(end);
        if (pos1 == -1 || pos2 == -1) { break; }
        s = s.substring(0,pos1) + s.substring(pos2+end.length);
    }
    return s;
}
```

This allows to remove all text in a specific element (`script` in your case).

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function(){
   var body = String(document.body.innerHTML).replace("...");
   document.body.innerHTML = body;

}
```

Comment: none in particular, only one practice for if the item is null. thanks for your wisdom